# Is there any way to add font color and edit text from a span + script that takes data from 3rd party websites?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using the IMDb widget provided in their website and am currently displaying in my blog the related rating score of a couple of movies I have recently reviewed.

The code is this:

```
<span itemprop="ratingValue" class="imdbRatingPlugin" data-title="[imdb_movie_shortcode]" data-style="p3"></span><script>(function(d,s,id){var js,stags=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; if(d.getElementById(id)){return;}js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id; js.src="http://g-ec2.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/imdb/plugins/rating/js/rating.min.js"; stags.parentNode.insertBefore(js,stags);})(document,'script','imdb-rating-api');</script></span>
```

Current result is something like "`7.0/10 683,075 votes`" typed in dark grey colour.
I would like to first change the printed info font color into white. And second, to edit the '`votes`' word into 'hello'.

Is there any way to do this?

I tried with `<span style="color:white;">` but it doesn't seem to work.

P.S. Please anybody help me formatting the code above with the stackoverflow builder. I have no idea how to find it. It is currently bad to read.

?

```js
(function(d,s,id){var js,stags=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; if(d.getElementById(id)){return;}js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id; js.src="http://g-ec2.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/imdb/plugins/rating/js/rating.min.js"; stags.parentNode.insertBefore(js,stags);})(document,'script','imdb-rating-api');
```

```html
<span itemprop="ratingValue" class="imdbRatingPlugin" data-title="tt0499549" data-style="p3"></span>
```

Comment: Does `<span style="color:white !important;">` work? I was unable to test your code because it does not seem to be retrieving the data with just the code you have posted. I suggest including more of your code with a snippet, so that it reproduces what you are seeing. You can add a code snippet by editing your post and pressing `ctrl + M` or selecting the "Javascript/HTML/CSS" snippet button (the one with the `<>` brackets) at the top of the editor box. If you have links to external source scripts  that this code is dependent on, be sure to include those in your snippet.

Comment: Tried, but doesn't seem to work here. The code I provided in the question is complete and working if you just turn [imdb_movie_shortcode] into tt0499549 (which is a random shortcode I took, related to Avatar movie in this case.

Comment: You can try the code from origin here, just search a random movie and choose style type 3. https://www.imdb.com/plugins